# Issue installing Ruby 2.5.0 on macos

Tags: ruby, terminal, version

I'm trying to work on a new app which I cloned from a repository, so I enter in the file and got this:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, 
it is all fine - Heroku does that too, 
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/cathleenhenninot/Desktop/omnimeta-schema-manager/Gemfile'. 
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'. 
Required ruby-2.5.0 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.5.0"'
```

ok, so I'm actually in ruby 2.5.1, should I install the ruby 2.5.0? Is it an obligation to work on the same version as the repository?

I tried and run `rvm install "ruby-2.5.0"`
and i got this:

```
Found old RVM 1.29.7-next - updating.
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
No GPG software exists to validate rvm-installer, skipping.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/cathleenhenninot/.mkshrc /Users/cathleenhenninot/.profile /Users/cathleenhenninot/.bashrc.
    RVM PATH line not found for Zsh, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/cathleenhenninot/.profile /Users/cathleenhenninot/.bash_profile /Users/cathleenhenninot/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


RVM reloaded!
ruby-2.5.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.5.0 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.5.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.0 - #downloading ruby-2.5.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.5.0 - #extracting ruby-2.5.0 to /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.0 - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #applying patch /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.5.0/prelude_gcc_diagnostic.patch - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #applying patch /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.5.0/libressl_2_7.patch - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #configuring - please wait
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0  --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/log/1552667484_ruby-2.5.0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

An error stop the installation, how do I finish the installation of ruby 2.5.0? Any help would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: what does the log file say?  (hint: its location is in the line above the error message)

Comment: `ruby-2.5.0 - #downloading ruby-2.5.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.5.0 - #extracting ruby-2.5.0 to /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.0 - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #applying patch /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.5.0/prelude_gcc_diagnostic.patch - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #applying patch /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.5.0/libressl_2_7.patch - please wait
ruby-2.5.0 - #configuring - please wait`

Comment: Looks like the #configuring part has the error?

Comment: @BillDoughty was referring to this "please read /Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/log/1552667484_ruby-2.5.0/configure.log"

Comment: what is your `rvm` version?

Comment: there seems to be issues with your installation from this line `Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/cathleenhenninot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0  --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
`

Comment: ah! sorry for the bad answer @BillDoughty

Comment: @StevenAguilar my version of rvm: rvm 1.29.7-next